# Need help to understand the code with pointers and arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I need to understand what the commented line does?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun(char**);

int main()
{
    char *argv[] = {"ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"};
    fun(argv);
    return 0;
}
void fun(char **p)
{
    char *t;
    t = (p+= sizeof(int))[-1]; //what this line does? //[-1] does what?
    printf("%s\n", t);
}
```

Comment: Somebody's already posted an answer, but I'm pretty sure this is a homework problem, and you'd in the long run be much better off actually *running* this code on your computer. If you run it you'll be able to see exactly what that line is doing.

Comment: @lxt : I already run it and saw output as `gh` which to me was strange.That's why I asked to understand the code not to tell the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `int` is 4 bytes in your machine, then replace `sizeof(int)` with 4:

```
t = (p+= 4))[-1];
```

is just to move forward the pointer `p` 4 elements, and move backward 1 element, then get the element.

In this example, the array has 4 elements, so move forward to one past the end, and move backward to the last element, which is `"gh"`.

Several note:

- `a[-1]` is just `*(a - 1)`.
- You need to make sure when you do pointer arithmetic, they are always pointing an element in an array or one  past the end.
- Also the name `argv` is not a good idea, since we usually use it to
  refer to the parameter of `main`.

Answer (score 1):

the `-1` just means it goes to the previous item:

```
x[-1]=*(x-1)
```

the whole line is

```
*(x+sizeof(int)-1)
```

sizeof(int) is probably 4 so the line is equals:

```
*(x+4-1)=*(x+3)=x[3]="gh"
```

Answer (score 0):

initally `**p` contains address of `argv[0]` element ie `"ab"`.it is then incremented by `2` **(size of int given as 2 bytes)**.now it point to `"ef"`.It is then decremented by `-1`.so finally points to `"cd"`.so it print value of `t` as `"cd"`.

**Note:**

> Since C is a machine dependent language sizeof(int) may return
>   different values.
>
> The output for the above program will be cd in Windows (Turbo C) and
>   gh in Linux (GCC).
>
> To understand it better, compile and execute the above program in
>   Windows (with Turbo C compiler) and in Linux (GCC compiler).