# can someone explain this assignment,double pointer and output

Tags: c, function

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 void fun(char**);

 int main()
 {
     char *argv[] = {"ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"};
     fun(argv);
     return 0;
 }
 void fun(char **p)
 {
     char *t;
     t = (p+= sizeof(int))[-1];
     printf("%s\n", t);
 }
```

can some one explain me that assignment t = (p+= sizeof(int))[-1]; .. The ans given is cd ..

Comment: If that's an actual assignment from an educational course of some sort, and the answer is stated as `cd`, my honest advice would be to run a mile.

Comment: p is increased by size of int, then it is dereferenced by selecting the index right before it. This is technically undefined behavior as the program cannot really do negative array indexes.

Comment: Of course you can use negative indexes. As long as adding the negative index results in a pointer that is valid.

Comment: `"cd"`??? The behavior of this code depends on the `sizeof(int)`, which is platform-dependent. However, for most modern platforms `sizeof(int) == 4` and the output is `"gh"`. Did you run it on some old/exotic platform with `sizeof(int) == 2`? That's the only way to get `"cd"` printed.

Comment: @AndreyT : In web its given as "cd" .. My compiler actually gives "gh"

Comment: @Siva Praveen: Well, as I said, the output is platform-dependent. There's no single "correct " answer about what this program will output. It might not output anything at all and just crash, if `sizeof(int)` happens to be greater than 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is intended to confuse you. Explaining it wouldn't be really helpful, because it would stop you from learning to understand badly written code.

The code was probably written a long time ago, in a time of 8 bit and 16 bit computers, when sizeof (int) was 2. Just assume that sizeof (int) = 2, and carefully go through the code step by step.

Comment: @Siva Praveen: There's no such thing as "double pointer" as an independent concept. "Double pointer" is just a regular single pointer. It just so happened that the pointee happened to be a pointer as well.

Comment: Is this the way i should think? .. t = (p+2)[-1] ,which is  t = (p+1) .. which is "cd"

Comment: @Siva Praveen: Close, but with some corrections. `t = (p + 2)[-1]` is equivalent to `t = *(p + 1)`. You forgot the `*` bit.

Answer (score 0):

it is really bad code, the answer is "cd" because p is first incremented by 2 and set to p[2] from p[0]. It is then decremented by 1 and set to p[1] which is pointing to the string "cd". It is a double pointer because the string "cd" itself generates a pointer.

The answer is dependent on your system, on most systems it would point to p[3].

I agree this code is written to confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

initally `**p` contains address of `argv[0]` element ie `"ab"`.it is then incremented by `2` **(size of int given as 2 bytes)**.now it point to `"ef"`.It is then decremented by `-1`.so finally points to `"cd"`.so it print value of `t` as `"cd"`.

You can find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813603/need-help-to-understand-the-code-with-pointers-and-arrays-in-c)